# Flutter: ¿Cómo actualizar el token de firebase messaging luego de actualizar la app?

Tags: flutter

Tengo una aplicación que usa el complemento **firebase_messaging** y quisiera actualizar el token cada vez que se actualiza la app en las tiendas (app store y play store)

Al parecer al actualizar no se siguen recibiendo las notificaciones.

¿Realmente es necesario actualizar el token?

Comment: Si, el token expira cada cierto tiempo, tienes que mandar al backend el nuevo código, lo que algunos hacen es obtener un identificador único del dispositivo, lo pueden hacer con un plugin, luego envian ese identificador con el token, entonces si ya existe un token, lo reemplazan.

Answer (score 0):

Pues a mi no me se actualiza el token si la persona reinstala la app, pero si desinstalan la app y vuelven a instalarla el token cambia, lo que hago por lo general es actualizar el token en BD cuando eso sucede.